# Splunk - find new values that only appear after a certain date

Tags: splunk

So I am going through logs and I want to find IPs that have only logged in after a certain date, but do not show up at all before.  I am not sure how to do this in Splunk but I know it is possible.  Let's say that the date is 10/1/2022 and the field is IP.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the [following](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions#strptime.28X.2CY.29) should [work](https://strftime.org):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp ip=* earliest=0
| stats min(_time) as early by ip
| where early>strptime("10/01/2022","%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming yours logs functional timestamps are equivalent to Splunk indextime, the most efficient way to do that is to specify your time range directly in ‘search terms’ part of your search

For example :

```
index=<yourIndex>
source=<yourSource>
earliest=01/10/2022:00:00:00
latest=now
| < ... rest of your search ... >
```

You can also achieve this with using the ‘Time Picker’ in the UI

*[Link to documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.2/Search/Specifytimemodifiersinyoursearch)*